# how to upload subtitle srt file from backend

Tags: youtube, srt

need to upload an SRT file for video subtitles using PHP for YOUTUBE URL and display the subtitles based on SRT file on webpage.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, please read this article before asking question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: consider that adding some code snippet, details, explanation about your problem, errors log or any information to help others answer your question.